# Shopify Custom Pixel and GA4 WEB/ Server Container

Tags: events, shopify, e-commerce, google-tag-manager, google-analytics-4

Wondering if anyone has experience with Shopify Custom Pixels, and sending checkout event with lineitem data to it?

Kind of following the guide (https://help.shopify.com/en/manual/promoting-marketing/pixels/custom-pixels/gtm-tutorial) but trying to include items.

This pushes the items in the datalayer to ecommerce.items, which I am sending in the datalayer.

I catch it in GTM server, but cant seem to onsend it to GA4

[image]

The Trigger to GA4 is here.

[image]